# Apache web server multiple workers

Tags: apache, tomcat, ajp

We have a webserver running apache 2.2, which connects to tomcat 5.5 in another server (say, **repserver**). This is done through **ajp1.3** protocol, with **mod_jk** `workers.properties` file defining an ajp13 worker.

The `workers.properties` file contains:

```
ps=\
worker.ajp13.type=ajp13
worker.list=ajp13
worker.ajp13.port=8009
worker.ajp13.host=#HOSTNAME
```

The `httpd.conf` file is using these three lines:

```
JkMount /* ajp13
JkMount /#Link1/* ajp13
JkMount /#Link2/* ajp13
```

Now we have another instance of tomcat 7 in the **repserver**, and we need the webserver to connect to this instance as well. I have defined the listening port for ajp as `9009` in this instance of tomcat.
This contains `link3` and `link4`.

How can I define another worker to connect to these links?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a load balancer in that case:

Change your workers.properties to this:

```
worker.list=balancer

#lb config
worker.balancer.type=lb
worker.balancer.sticky_session=1
worker.balancer.balance_workers=ajp13,tomcat7

#(ajp13 is not a good name for a worker/server node)
worker.ajp13.type=ajp13
worker.ajp13.port=8009
worker.ajp13.host=#HOSTNAME

worker.tomcat7.type=ajp13
worker.tomcat7.port=9009
worker.tomcat7.host=#IP/HOSTNAME
```

Open server.xml of Tomcat 7 and define the jvmRoute (do that in Tomcat 5 too, if not still happend):

```
<Engine jvmRoute="tomcat7" name="Catalina" ...>
```

Map applications to the new Tomcat 7:

```
JkMount /APPLICATION_NAME   balancer
JkMount /APPLICATION_NAME/* balancer
```